# sed: excluding serveral part strings from matched pattern

Tags: sed, replace

So the idea is to replace matched pattern 
`nas_...` with `nas_$SCL` using $SCL variable in a file, but excluding 2 exact matches `nas_mba && nas_tvr`, which should not be replaced

So far I've got code excluding both matches, but also interfering with other unwanted matches

```
sed -i "s/nas_[^mt][^bv][^ar]/nas_$SCL/gI" filename.xml
```

How can I exclude only those 2 exact matches?

**Update**:
So far I've found next solution

```
sed -i "/(nas_mba|nas_tvr)/! s/nas_.../nas_$SCL/"
```

but it skips a whole line if it has a match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
sed -E '/(nas_mba|nas_tvr)/! s/nas_.../nas_bar/'
```

Example:

```
echo "nas_mba
nas_tvr
nas_foo" | sed -E '/(nas_mba|nas_tvr)/! s/nas_.../nas_bar/'
nas_mba
nas_tvr
nas_bar
```

Only `nas_foo` in the original text is replaced, while both `nas_mba` and `nas_tvr` are left untouched.

Another example with more lines:

```
echo "nas_hat
> nas_mba
> nas_foo
> nas_hat
> nat_tvr
> nas_cat
> nas_dog" | sed -E '/(nas_mba|nas_tvr)/! s/nas_.../nas_bar/'
nas_bar
nas_mba
nas_bar
nas_bar
nat_tvr
nas_bar
nas_bar
```

If you want to change in place, just add the `-i` option (if you use GNU `sed` you don't need `-i ""` simply `-i` would suffice):

```
sed -E -i "" '/(nas_mba|nas_tvr)/! s/nas_.../nas_bar/' nas.txt 
cat nas.txt 
nas_bar
nas_mba
nas_bar
nas_bar
nat_tvr
nas_bar
nas_bar
```

---

Tested under Mac OS X 10.11.6 and BSD `sed`.

Comment: yes, this is a good example, but this should be replace lines in a file, thus needing -i flag

Comment: Well, simply add the `-i` flag. See my edit.

Comment: cheers, works as intended

Comment: @MaxShepelev You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If perl is an option, you could use *lookahead*:

```
export SCL
perl -pe 's/nas_(?!mba|tvr)\w*/nas_$ENV{SCL}/g' file
```

(note that this assumes the sequences you **do** want to match consist of word characters - it can be modified if that's not the case).